# WebClient Headers property missing Add method?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, webclient

In .NET (for Windows Phone), I'm trying to use the WebClient class to send XML to a web service.  The examples I found modify add headers with an Add method, but I am getting an error that the Add method could not be found:

```
using System.Net;
...
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "text/xml");
```

Am I just missing a reference somewhere or has this been changed?  I also don't have a Set method listed either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wc.Headers["ContentType"] = "text/xml";

Comment: This works, although I'm still left wondering where my Add method got to.